# Setting up subdomain of existing site with local apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, virtualhost

I am developing a site on my local machine and want to point a subdomain of an existing site to my localhost's subdomain. A concrete example:

I have a normal running apache on port 80, and a virtual host on port 8081. I want to point `http://dev.google.com` to my virtual host.

I've tried adding it to the hosts file, but ports don't work there.

Am using Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the virtual host running on port 8081 and make it listen op port 80. Your vhosts should look somewhat like this:

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
ServerName google.com
DocumentRoot c:/htdocs/www/main
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
ServerName dev.google.com
DocumentRoot c:/htdocs/www/dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ah, I see now, so both should listen to port 80, but they should be name-based hosts. Think I also have to uncomment the line `NameVirtualHost *:80` in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. You can also use a * instead of the IP, that way your sites can be accessed from all your interfaces.